# PowerBuilder 12.5 Reports Issue

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a report suppose named as ABC. This ABC report has a computed field, which counts some values using some formulae. Now, in some other report DEF, in computed field, I need result values coming from ABC. How can I manage this?

Dummy values for understanding

ABC report suppose has result 9500

This result 9500 I need in report DEF

Answer (score 0):

I'm left making a few assumptions about how these reports relate to one another. However, here's a few sample possibilities, each starting with a GetItem*() of the value into a Powerscript variable.

SetItem() the value into one or more rows.

Modify() the formula to include the hard-coded value.

Modify() the text value of a hidden statictext object on the DataWindow to the passed value and have the formula convert and use that value.

Pass the value is as a retrieval argument.

Instead of passing values between reports, make the report encapsulated and repeat the value calculation in the DataWindow's SQL.

These ideas should help you get inspired to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

all counts on summary, header and footer are predefined as row =1 if datawindow has data.

### sample

```
long ll_compute_count = 0
if dw_ABC.rowcount() > 0 then  
 ll_compute_count = dw_ABC.object.name_of_computefield [1]
end if
```

Happy Coding.
from pb developer (Indo)